# NumberFormatter format inconsistency between PHP version/Docker image

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux, icu

I'm currently doing an upgrade from PHP 7.1 to 7.2. We have a dockerised setup with custom alpine images. The upgrade is fairly painless but our test suite failed on one thing which isn't obvious to fix.

We have the following code (abbreviated for brevity) running in a test:

```php
$numberFormatter = \NumberFormatter::create('en', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formattedCost = $numberFormatter->formatCurrency(
    false, null
);
var_dump($formattedCost);
```

We're getting very different output in our old and new images though.

PHP 7.1 on an image based on `php:7.1.30-fpm-alpine3.10`

```php
bool(false)
```

PHP 7.2 on an image based on `php:7.2.22-fpm-alpine3.10`

```php
string(6) "¤0.00"
```

The `¤` character is the unicode currency symbol character.

I've checked a few PHP online testers and none seem to match this behaviour. It appears the expected behaviour should be to return false on all PHP versions.

I was wondering if this is related to underlying differences in the Intl extension / ICU. Our 7.1 image has the following:

```
version => 1.1.0
ICU version => 59.1
ICU Data version => 59.1
```

and the 7.2 version has these

```
version => 1.1.0
ICU version => 64.2
ICU Data version => 64.2
```

I'm not sure though why the same Alpine OS 3.10 with the same intl extension version (1.1.0) would install drastically different ICU versions.

Comment: Just cranking up a couple of VMs... so far I've got `string(6) "¤0.00"` on a Debian 9 VM with PHP 7.2 (ICU/data version 64.1) ...

Comment: Definitely looks like an ICU version thing rather than PHP version, I've got a Debian box with PHP 7.1 which is also running ICU 64.1 and that's also getting `string(6) "¤0.00" ` ... technically that's as close to *false* as you're likely to get with an actual currency string ... but it ain't going to evaluate as false ... doesn't seem to match the documentation does it?

Comment: ... and on a Windows box with PHP 7.1 and ICU/Data version 57.1, I get a warning (*NumberFormatter::formatCurrency(): Number formatting failed*) and `bool(false)` - so it *looks* like something's changed in how `false` is type juggled before it's formatted.

Comment: ... ah, not the type juggling, it's the `NULL` currency - changing the currency to `EUR` on the Windows box gives `string(7) "€0.00"` so it's juggling `false` to `0` and formatting that fine, as long as it's got a currency to work with. *nix will happily use the `¤` character